# How to deploy installation file for .NET program with Rider IDE?

Tags: c#, .net, rider

I am trying to create a Windows setup file for my .NET project. My IDE is Rider.

Can I use ClickOnce within Rider?

I looked into Squirrel but it seems it does not provide a way to present user with prompts that are needed at the installation, but the update mechanism it has is very smooth. It also works for .NET Framework but doesn’t work for .NETCoreApp so I would need to implement the installer and updater as separate applications.

What are my other options if I wish to stay with Rider only?

Comment: What prompts would you need at installation time? Also did you investigate which commandline options you have available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2019

Comment: I need to present the user with terms of service and give him the ability to change installation folder and decide if he wants to have a desktop shortcut and perhaps some other initial settings options for the application. Thank you for reminding me of the command line option, I missed it.

Comment: using debugger should help